# Object missing parts in the viewport using eevee

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I was working on a model inside blender 2.83 and suddenly it turned into like broken object. The problem remains in rendered mode in (eevee)

[image]

but disappeared in cycles rendered mode.

Comment: Please attach your simplified  blend . It can be a part of model just with issue still visible. Use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com BTW your screen is from Solid mode.

Comment: You may try adjusting the viewport clipping, or press , on the nupad with the object selected